# File structure in database

Tags: php, database, file, tree

I'm making a simple file listing function in PHP, just to recursively list all the files in a directory. 
The function I have right now looks something like this:

```
<?php
function listFiles($dir){
    echo "<ul class=\"filebrowser\">";
    $dirCont = scandir($dir);           // scan the whole directory
    sortFoldersFirst($dirCont,$dir);    // sort alphabetically, folders first
    foreach ($dirCont as $value) {
        if (!in_array($value,array(".","..",".deleted"))){ // don't list the parent folder, current folder, or the (hidden) .deleted folder
            if (is_dir($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value)){   // if it's a folder
                echo "<h3 class=\"filebrowser\">"  . $value . "</h3>"; // show the folder name
                listFiles($dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $value);  // do the same again for the child folder
            } else {
                echo "<li><a href=\"".$dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$value."\">".$value."</a></li>";  // a link to the file
            }
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
?>
```

This gives me something like this:

[image]

This technique works just fine, however, I'd like to store a little more information about the files, like the author, comments, maybe a link to a thumbnail etc.
I'd like to get rid of the 'real' directory structure, and store everything in a database. (Just all files in 1 big folder, and links to the files in the database, not the actual files)
How can I store this information in the database, and how can I get it back out, without changing the result in the browser.
In other words: how can I get the tree structure in and out of the database, and how do I recursively loop through it.

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/854736/6356744).
It shows how to make a database tree structure by saving the parent folder's id for every file/folder. This makes it easy to get the full path of a file, but it seems a bit less convenient to list all contents of a folder. 
Is there a better solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance,
Pieter

Comment: *"but it seems a bit less convenient to list all contents of a folder"* - The thing is with a database, it's a lot easier to maintain. What you're asking would require to use text files and those have pros & cons. The cons, being maintaining them and probably having to keep those out of the public area, should you not want prying eyes in there. That's just *"my 2 cents"* of course.

Comment: Search for "sql adjacency list", "sql materialized path" and "sql transitive closure".

Comment: Consider to use `MySQL`. `PDO` is better or at worst case `MySQLi`.